# Why am i getting the 'expected declaration specifier' for waitpid()?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  
  for(int i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++){
    int status;
    if(fork() != 0){
        //Parent Code
        pid_t waitpid( 1, &status, 0);
        break;
    }
    
  }
  
  
  
  FILE *out = fopen("PartC.txt", "a");
  printf("PID: %d ; PPID: %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
  fprintf(out, "%d ; %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 
  return 0;
}
```

```
error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
   19 |     pid_t waitpid( 1, &status, 0);
      |                    ^
main.c:19:23: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
   19 |     pid_t waitpid( 1, &status, 0);
      |                       ^
main.c:19:32: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
   19 |     pid_t waitpid( 1, &status, 0);
      |                                ^
```

i dont understand why i am getting this error as i have tried changinf around everything.

Comment: `pid_t waitpid( 1, &status, 0);` Explain what the `pid_t` is doing there.

Comment: @kaylum it wasnt there as my starter code but when looking it up thats what i seen was in front of waipid on all examples. i just assumed

Comment: i added ```  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/wait.h>``` to the code and it gives no error but now its not printing out the file needed.

Answer (score 1):

You copied `pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *wstatus, int options);` from the man page, changed the arguments but forgot to either remove or change the return type to a variable:

```
pid_t child_pid = waitpid( 1, &status, 0);
```

Comment: main.c:19:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘waitpid’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   19 |     pid_t pid = waitpid( -1, &status, 0);
      |                 ^~~~~~~
This is the error i get. i tried this before the post and it eas the same thing.

Comment: Sorry for stating the obvious but this is *not* the same error message.  On linux you fix your new problem by including the two header files sys/types.h and sys/wait.h.

Comment: i added that to the code doing more research but it wouldn't print out my file at the end. but if I remove it, I get that error message from using your changes.